# Arrays and methods

Tags: java

I am new to java and I really need some help with this project. I am have no idea where to go from here.I am writing a program that allows the user to input as many numbers as he wants up to 100. At any time he can hit q and the loop should stop running. Once it stops then  my program displays the minimum and maximum numbers for inputted numbers on the console and also calculates/displays the count, sum, and average of all inputted numbers on the console.

The calculation and program's console output should be implemented in their own methods. I just need some guidance
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double [] myList = new double[100]; 


         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter floating point numbers"); 
        for ( int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
            myList[i] = input.nextDouble(); 

        public static void stopInput(double [] array){

        }

        public static void calculate(){

        }
}
}
```

Comment: Start by writing a simple, working program with only a limited subset of the functionality you need.  Then add each piece of additional functionality, piece by piece.  For instance, start by writing a program which  just accepts input and echos it back until you get your user interface correct.  Then start worrying about the math bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing before I give you the answer

This:

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double [] myList = new double[100]; 


     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter floating point numbers"); 
    for ( int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
        myList[i] = input.nextDouble(); 

    public static void stopInput(double [] array){

    }

    public static void calculate(){

    }
```

}
}

Should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double [] myList = new double[100]; 
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter floating point numbers"); 
        for ( int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
            myList[i] = input.nextDouble();
     }
public static void calculate(){
}
public static void stopInput(double [] array){
}
```

You can not declare a method within another method.

Now, have `test` implement `KeyboardListener`

`public class test implements KeyboardListener`

KeyboardListener is an `event handler` class that listens for 3 things.

- KeyPressed

Pressing a key invokes this method

- KeyReleased

Releasing a key, or the motion of the key coming up after being pressed, invokes this method

- KeyTyped

Pressing and releasing invokes this method

When using an `event listener` they have methods that you have to include with them, those 3 having to go with KeyboardListener.

Within KeyPressed, you can say

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyChar() == 'q'){
        //Whatever goes here
    }
}
```

This will let you do whatever you tell it to do when a user types q.

For the calculate method, have it in another for loop (since with Arrays, any `int` not entered, is 0)

```
for(int i = 0; i<myList.length; i++){
        sum += myList[i];
    }
```

And so on for the other types of math.

For the count and average, just make another array (of int count size) and run it through a for loop again and for every number that isnt 0, add one to count and throw it in the other array. Then run it through one last for loop, just like the sum, except divide it by `//array name//.length` to get the average.